# Can't install wine, updating from such a repository can't be done securely

Tags: wine

I tried to install wine using terminal and it gives an error at the third step.

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'

Hit:1http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Hit:3http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Ign:4http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu focal InRelease  
Get:5http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]   
Hit:6http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Err:7http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu focal Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:8https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease         
Get:9http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1.571 kB]
Get:10http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [601 kB]
Get:11http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [302 kB]
Get:12http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [801 kB]
Get:13http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Translation-en [114 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                    
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
stefan@stefan-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Get:3http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]   
Get:4http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]      
Ign:5http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu focal InRelease  
Hit:6http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Err:7http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu focal Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:8https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Get:9http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40,6 kB]
Get:10http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [66,3 kB]
Get:11http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.464 B]
Reading package lists... Done     
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: The `codeblocks-devs` repository does not have anything for Ubuntu 20.04. Looking at [the distribution list](http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu/dists/), 19.10 was the last version they supported 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)